# Cannot Save native language (Telugu) from Code Igniter to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, user-input, utf

Im working on a PHP API and a CodeIgniter website, i need to post/get a form to Database(MYSQL), i wrote direct API for Android not using any framework but works fine.

**PHP API POST REQUEST CODE:**

```
$postDescription = strip_tags($_REQUEST['postDescription']);
$stmtl = $user->runQuery("INSERT INTO posts(postID,userID,postDescription) VALUES('','".$userID."','".$postDescription."')");
```

**CodeIgniter Code for website:**

```
$data = array('postDescription' => $this->input->post('postDescription'),);
return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
```

The problem is the post data content in native language is inserting and getting to and from database fine, But getting like this content while posting from codeigniter website ????????  or showing the data from android posted content like `°¤à°¾à°¡à±‡à°ªà°²à±à°²à°¿ à°•à±à°¯à°¾à°‚à°ªà`

I need to post/display native language content to and from both android and website.

Demo URL: http://arunahospitals.com/

Comment: Did you tried this header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Make sure the coalition of your table is utf8mb4

Comment: tried those 2 options!
the data which is posted from can only visible to those(android,web)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `database->table->column's` Collation property to `utf16/utf32` . Suppose your column name "posts" then you can try with changing column "posts" Collation property to `utf16/utf32`.

Comment: changed to utf16 but same error the android posted  is visible to android and codeigniter posted data is only visible to web

Comment: In MySQL column:

The data from codeigniter post is saving as రిపోర్ట్స్, వీడియోలు, the original native native,

The data from Android via PHP API is saving as à°ªà±‹à°°à±à°Ÿà±à°¸à±, à

Comment: did you try utf32 @Sailesh ?